# recurly error message: cannot import name Account

Tags: python, recurly

Hello I've followed these steps:
on my code folder

```
pip install recurly
```

Create code:

```
import recurly
from recurly import Account


recurly.SUBDOMAIN = 'mi-domain'
recurly.API_KEY = 'abdcdddd1d7445fba86b5ca35eef00d5'
recurly.DEFAULT_CURRENCY = 'USD'
account = Account.get('id45')
account.delete()
```

and when I try to execute code above
I get

> ImportError: cannot import name Account

Why is it that imports recurly with no problem but cannot import resources?

Comment: Try to run the first line only. It works?

Comment: Yes. If I just execute import recurly it works ok, but if I execute "from recurly import Account" I get error stated above

Comment: What about `recurly.Account`?

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to call `recurly.Account.get('id45')` to get the account you'd like. You can find an example with correct syntax here: https://github.com/recurly/recurly-js-examples/blob/master/api/python/app.py#L70